# How to slide-out a submenu from under the navigation bar using CSS transition?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I've been trying to create a transition effect where, on hover, a sub menu slides out from underneath the main navigation bar. So far, I've got all the elements in place and wasted HOURS playing around with different methods from various posts, but to no avail.

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/account144/98vxmgLL/).

I'm guessing I'm gonna have to get rid of `display: none -> display: block` way of hiding the submenu as its no good for transitions but various other methods such as transitioning `max-height`, `opacity`, pulling it down from a massive `top` value etc have failed. With the inflated `top` value method, the submenu slides over everything rather than under and changing z-index values somehow pushes it behind EVERYTHING while turning the background transparent. Very weird behaviour.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could explain to me how to go about creating a smooth slide-out transition for the sub-menu.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transforming the scale or transitioning the `max-height: 0` is a better option for navigational elements.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atagref/7ey4p04e/1/)

If the initial state of the element is "display: none" it is passed over in the DOM which will hide that element (as well as any children) from assistive technology.

Also, you can use a [sibling sectors](https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/) to select .dropdown, instead of overly nesting elements

Adjacent sibling: `.dropbtn:hover + .dropdown_content`

Comment: Very clean solution, thank you very much :). I nearly got to this stage before but didn't think of `overflow: hidden` to handle spilled content, what an absolute idiot I am!

Answer (score 1):

Working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/6umr3733/1/

**Procedure:** we set the value of `top` for the dropdown to -100%. This puts it out of the screen. We give it a `transition` value for it to be smooth when it goes down.

```
.dropdown_content {
  line-height: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top:-100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index:-10;
  width: 120%;
  left: -20%;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

When we hover over `dropdown`, your div goes down by 200%, that is, to its original position.

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown_content {
  top:100%;
}
```

Hope I helped, good luck.

Comment: I tried this before but if you add content after the header, the submenu becomes transparent for some reason; [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/account144/6umr3733/3/). Any idea how to solve that? TBH I just want to know what the hell causes that behaviour at this point lol.

Comment: You need to re-structure your HTML so that the dropdown is not a child element of the nav anymore. I'll help you with it later, I'm kind of busy now.

Comment: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/account144/98vxmgLL/11/), is the latest version which does what I want it to do using the `max-height` property. However, I still haven't figured out exactly why your version causes the transparent background so I'd really appreciate it if a precise explanation is found for the problem. Thank you very much for your time Fausto :).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `transform: scaleY();` attribute to squash the submenu to 0 when hidden, and to 1 when visible.

Check [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/98vxmgLL/10/)

Just remove the `Display` attributes, and add a `transition`, and `transform: scaleY(0); transform-origin: 0 0;` when is normal, and `transform: scaleY(1);` when hover to `.dropdown_content`.